# Jquery Bullseye viewport detection integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, detection, viewport, bullseye

I would like to use [Jquery Bullseye](http://static.pixeltango.com/jQuery/Bullseye/) to show a div when scrolled down.
My HTML is

```
<div class="a preview"></div>
<div class="b preview"></div>
<div>
    <div class="a-content content">
        <p>some content (1)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="b-content content">
        <p>some content (2)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my Javascript (for the Bullseye script)

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {

$('.a').bind('viewportenter', function(e) {
$(".content-1 div").hide('blind', { direction: "up" });
$(".a-content").siblings().hide('blind', { direction: "up" });
$(".a-content").show('blind', { direction: "up" });
}).bullseye();
```

}); 
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add the if 'e.type ...' so it works. My Javascript looks like this now:

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $(function () {


$('.functions')
.bind('enterviewport', function (e) {
            if (e.type == 'enterviewport')
               $(".b-content").toggle('blind', { direction: "up" });
        })
.bullseye()
           .addClass('outline');

    }); });
```

But how do I insert the options for Bullseye? For example I want to change the value of extendHeight to 50px. How do I do that?